# What are these insects on my Japanese maple tree?

Tags: pests, insects, japanese-maple

[image: Tree covered in small black insects]

I live in Sweden and have a Japanese maple tree in a pot on my balcony. This October I saw maybe hundreds of small insects on my tree which I believe caused the leaves to crumble and fall. Which to me indicates that these insects are draining my tree of nutrition.

I have searched for days for an answer. The insects look different to each other. What is this?

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  To identify the insects we need a closeup picture.  Is there any sticky sap on the branches or ground near it?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. I can't upload any images. Is it a problem on the website?

Comment: IMG_1356.PNG testing

Comment: the picture is too big:  maximum size of 2 Mb. change the resolution on your camera or use paint to resize